# Reactjs: How do i send a fetched API data from a component to a dynamic route component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi everyone I have this project, a recipe web app for me to learn react better
[image]

this is the homepage component where i get the data from the API
[image]

Recipes Component: the data from the useState is looped through and passed to the Recipes components
[image: Recipes component]

Now i wanted create a component where when a user clicks on the content it redirect him/her to a new page

[image: recipe component]

. The problem is that i don't know how to pass data from the Recipes component to the Recipe and output them to the area marked by red pen. How do we do this without fetching another API (it's limited) and without using redux. Need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Recipes.js file, you can pass the state to the Link component.

```
<Link to={
  pathname: `/recipe/${props.title}`
  state={
    ingredients: props.ingredients
  }
} />
```

In Recipe.js file, this ingredients prop would be available in props.location.state.ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a router, you can pass down prop through it. Otherwise a store with `useReducer` could be a great solution.

Comment: Sorry for asking but how can do pass a prop through a component wrapped with a <Link>, am a newbie and am not familiar with redux

Comment: You can use the `to` prop, as object, of `<Link>` component, to forward a state to the target route component (ref. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link).